# Zero Division Error When Using Pytorch Mask RCNN

Tags: python, computer-vision, pytorch

I am using the pretrained torchvision MaskRCNN model on a dataset containing several videos, by passing the videos to the model frame by frame. However in the forward pass of the MaskRCNN model I get the following error statement:

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)

----> 1 output = model(images,targets)

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in __call__(self, *input, **kwargs)
    548             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    549         else:
--> 550             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    551         for hook in self._forward_hooks.values():
    552             hook_result = hook(self, input, result)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torchvision/models/detection/generalized_rcnn.py in forward(self, images, targets)
     64             original_image_sizes.append((val[0], val[1]))
     65 
---> 66         images, targets = self.transform(images, targets)
     67         features = self.backbone(images.tensors)
     68         if isinstance(features, torch.Tensor):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in __call__(self, *input, **kwargs)
    548             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    549         else:
--> 550             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    551         for hook in self._forward_hooks.values():
    552             hook_result = hook(self, input, result)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torchvision/models/detection/transform.py in forward(self, images, targets)
     42                 raise ValueError("images is expected to be a list of 3d tensors "
     43                                  "of shape [C, H, W], got {}".format(image.shape))
---> 44             image = self.normalize(image)
     45             image, target_index = self.resize(image, target_index)
     46             images[i] = image

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torchvision/models/detection/transform.py in normalize(self, image)
     62         mean = torch.as_tensor(self.image_mean, dtype=dtype, device=device)
     63         std = torch.as_tensor(self.image_std, dtype=dtype, device=device)
---> 64         return (image - mean[:, None, None]) / std[:, None, None]
     65 
     66     def torch_choice(self, l):

RuntimeError: ZeroDivisionError
```

My `images` in this code is a list of size 431, denoting the number of frames in the video, with each item of the list being a torch tensor of shape 3 x 256 x 320, denoting channels x height x width, respectively. `Targets` here contains the labels, masks and bounding boxes coordinates in the form of a dictionary of lists. The length of the `targets` list is also 431, with each item containing information about each individual frame.

The code I am using is similar to the one found [in this tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/torchvision_tutorial.html), except for the fact that that tutorial deals with static images, and I am working with videos, so I made only some minor changes to that code.

Comment: Are you setting the `image_std` argument when you create the `MaskRCNN`? If you do, what are the values? They must not be 0.

Comment: No I am not manually setting the image_std value myself. It's something torchvision is doing by itself.